# How to reduce size / quality of video file Android

Tags: android, video, file-upload, video-processing

I have been looking for solution here and google but I didn't find it.
I want to reduce video file from camera or gallery to send it to server.
please help me

Comment: Plz help me I don't know what to do. I'm lost

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compress Videos using android MediaCodec api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870729/compress-videos-using-android-mediacodec-api)

Comment: how did you reduce your file size?