# How to compress video for upload server?

Tags: android, video, compression

I'm trying to upload video file to server. But size is too large so how i can compress video before upload to server.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870729/compress-videos-using-android-mediacodec-api

Comment: You can also use ffmpeg which provides different utilities including compression too.

Answer (score -2):

You can try [Intel® INDE Media for Mobile Library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials)

Comment: Please don't write link-only answers.