# Compress video in android using using MediaCodec

Tags: android, compression, decode, encode, android-mediacodec

I am working on a project where i need to compress the video uploaded before sending it to server. I found similar questions like this ([Compress Videos using android MediaCodec api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870729/compress-videos-using-android-mediacodec-api)) where turorial he mentioned redirects to an invalid page( https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials). Other similar questions are redirecting to some libraries like silicompress.

Is there a simple way to achieve video compression using MediaCodec in android. A simple function where i can input "file url" and get the "video bytes data" as output in java?

Comment: Hello Abin, Android does not provide a simple api to MediaCodec out of the box. But there are some libraries that provide easy access to the hardware encoding [like this](https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder). If you want more flexibility you have to implement it yourself. Some useful info can be found [here](https://github.com/google/grafika) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec), for older apis refer to [here](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).

Comment: Btw,  Media for Mobile was opensourced and is available under [https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile](https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile)